# apt preferences pin: origin local?

Tags: debian, apt-get, deb, dpkg

I have dropped fglrx from my notebook and return to the free drivers but xfce4-power-manager fails to start. it was a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/821170)

I got apt-get source, apply the patch, build and install it. now all works perfect, I have reported this bug to debian. but now I want to hold this package to prevent upgrades for some time

I know that clumsy way is to bump the package build version part. for example 1.0.10-**5** and then hold package by a version:

```
Package: xfce4-power-manager
Pin: version 1.0.10-5
Pin-priority: 1001
```

I think the best way is to hold packages by the origin:

```
Package: xfce4-power-manager
Pin: origin "local origin?"
Pin-priority: 1001
```

Is this possible? I cant find this in docs

Comment: I answer with an apt_preferences approach, but you can also use a command like apt-mark hold instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "**run**" or "**now**" as the origin should work:

```
Package: xfce4-power-manager
Pin: release o=now
Pin-priority: 1001
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the man page (man 5 apt_preferences):

```
       This general-form entry in the APT preferences file applies only to
       groups of packages. For example, the following record assigns a
       high priority to all package versions available from the local
       site.

           Package: *
           Pin: origin ""
           Pin-Priority: 999
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. I have never used pinning to do this, so I'm not sure if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of apt (tested on Debian 9.8, stretch) support installing local debs, as long as a deb of the same name isn't available from a configured repo, in which case the repo version is preferred. For example, after commenting out the relevant repo from the local apt configuration, this works for me:

```
    sudo apt install ./packagename_0.0.1_all.deb
```

apt does need the `./` prefix or full path to find the local file.

Answer (score 1):

`release o=now` won't work, but `release a=now` will.

You can get various ways to refer to your machine's package sources from the output of `apt policy` (or `apt-cache policy`).  In `/etc/apt/preferences.d/myprefs` put:

```
Package: xfce4-power-manager
Pin: release a=now
Pin-priority: 1000
```

Then, if you run:

```
apt policy xfce4-power-manager
```

You'll see the installed version has priority 1000.