# How to make apt-get install prefer source from local iso?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, apt-get

If there are lots of sources in sourcelist, but I want apt-get to prefer source from local iso, rather than remote mirror, even when remote package is newer than local iso, I want apt-get to choose local iso, what I should do in order to make it works as I want?

This is my configuration of `/etc/apt/source.list`

> deb file:///home/jack/dsk/ lucid main restricted deb http://
>   us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted deb-src http:
>   //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted

I run apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, it seems apt-get try to download package from remote mirror:( this is not the thing I want:( 
I am sure ubuntu-desktop package is in my local iso mirror :( so how to make apt-get choose to install the package from `dsk/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-desktop_1.197_amd64.deb` rather than from http: // us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libc6 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10 ?

> find dsk/ | grep ubuntu-desktop
>   dsk/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-desktop_1.197_amd64.deb

After this operation, 2,191MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http: // us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libc6 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10 [4,389kB]

Comment: of course this is a problem related to software development, what a pity somebody just vote to close it, jesus:( maybe i should give an example that i am install gcc, but not kubuntu-desktop, but so what, they are in the same shoe:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for "apt pinning", that is to set preferences between different versions of packages in different repos or branches (stable, testing...).

See [apt preferences pin: origin local?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9165770/592540)

So based in that post you'd have to edit (or probably create because by default it does not exist) the file `/etc/apt/preferences` and put:

```
       Package: *
       Pin: origin ""
       Pin-Priority: 999
```